# wix/Detox Test can't find ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, detox

after running `detox test -c android`
it can't find my ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

> $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is not defined, set the path to the SDK installation
> directory into $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT,

it is already defined in my /.zshrc file

> export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/chiwan/Library/Android/sdk export
> PATH=/Users/chiwan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH export
> ANDROID_HOME=/Users/chiwan/Library/Android/sdk export
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/chiwan/Library/Android/sdk export
> ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/chiwan/.android/avd

System:
macOS - Big Sur 11.5.1 Apple Silicon Chip,
Platform: React Native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how my zshrc file looks like:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

try it + restart computer

Comment: You don't need to restart computer though lol Just run `source ~/.zshrc`